# Windows 7 font too large

Tags: windows, windows-7

I installed a theme ([metro lite](http://exsess.deviantart.com/art/Metro-Lite-Suite-259740013)) but now i have a problem: my font size is too large. How do i change back to the regular font? I've already tried using the normal "restore font" button and i've also tried changing the "MS Shell Dlg" back to "Segoe UI 9pt" in regedit.

Here's a picture of my problem:
[image: PROBLEM]

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

Appearantly my theme went into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts` and changed the value for Segoe UI (TrueType) to "". I just had to change it back to "Segoe UI.ttf"